# GitHub API POST 404 but GET OK

Tags: java, post, github-api

I'm getting mad on a simple task.
I made a dummy github account and repository just to make this experiment, so I can afford to share the security token too, so you can try on your end and see what is going on.
-I know I'm correctly autenticated
-The token has all the permissions

The following code gives me a 404

```
String requestBody = """
  {
  "owner" : "example42gdrive",
  "repo" : "Example1",
  "message" : "nextCommit",
  "content" : "newfilecontent",
  "sha" : "3db88097240677d34f3b2a4892f8d00f9c63d6dc"
  }
  """;
var url1="https://api.github.com/repos/example42gdrive/Example1/";
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
  .uri(URI.create(url1+"contents/bar/foo.txt"))
  .header("Authorization","token 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")
  .header("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3+json")
  .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(requestBody))
  .build();    
HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(
  request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
System.out.println(response.body().replace(",","\n"));
System.out.println(response.statusCode());//getting 404
```

But, if I comment the POST line, the request becomes a get, and I get the correct informations about reading the file /bar/foo.txt

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: For now, I just want to upload a different file instead of the one currently present.
Once this work, I want to explore the 'releases and artifacts' and learn how to upload/update those too.

Comment: from [the content documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents) to update or create via contents api it's a `PUT` method instead of `POST`